# Isolating JOIN predicates from syscomments

Tags: t-sql, analysis

In order to better understand all of the relationships in a database (physical and logical), I am looking to the stored procedures in order to extract the join predicates. I've got something I can work with, but its not complete.

The goal is to have 3 columns in the result:

1. The object name
2. The first join predicate
3. The second join predicate
4. The join type (inner, right, left)

   ```
   declare @Schema varchar(50),@SearchString   VARCHAR (10)

   set @SearchString = 'join';

   set  @Schema = 'dbo'


   declare @TextBuffer table 
   (
   SchemaName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   ObjectName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   Occurance int NOT NULL, 
   Txt varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
   Colid int
   )

   declare @Occurance table
   (
   SchemaName varchar(50)   NULL,
   ObjectName varchar(100)   NULL,
   Occurance  varchar(500) 
   )



   INSERT INTO @TextBuffer

   SELECT   DISTINCT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id),
                     o.name,
                     (LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, @SearchString, ''))) / LEN(@SearchString),
                     [text],
                     colid
   FROM     syscomments AS c
            INNER JOIN
            sys.objects AS o
            ON c.id = o.[object_id]
            INNER JOIN
            sys.schemas AS s
            ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
   WHERE    text LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
            AND SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @Schema
   ORDER BY colid, 3 DESC;



   DECLARE @Txt varchar(4000), @ObjectName varchar(100), @Occ int, @SchemaName varchar(100)


   declare @count int, @position int
   set @count = 0
   set @position = 0

   DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 

   SELECT Txt,ObjectName, Occurance, SchemaName from @TextBuffer
   OPEN my_cursor

   FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @Txt,@ObjectName,@Occ,@SchemaName

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN

       set @count =  @Occ


       while(@count > 0)
           begin 

           set @position =  charindex(@SearchString,@Txt) 

           insert into @Occurance select @SchemaName, @ObjectName, cast(substring(@Txt, @position, len(@Txt)) as varchar(500))

           set @Txt =  substring(substring(@Txt,len(@SearchString),len(@Txt)), @position, len(@Txt))


           set @count = @count -1

           end



   FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @Txt,@ObjectName,@Occ,@SchemaName
   END

   CLOSE my_cursor 
   DEALLOCATE my_cursor 


   select * from @Occurance
   ```

Comment: What does "not complete" mean? What precisely is missing? And taking the wider view, you will not be able to get this information reliably anyway because of dynamic SQL, procedures that call other procedures, queries embedded in client applications etc. It may still be possible to get information that's good enough for your needs, but it isn't clear what exactly what you expect.

Comment: The result contains too much text, I am looking specifically to isolate what is before the = and what is after in separate columns. I know its not a perfect science and I'm willing to live with whatever it generates.